# Popup is cropped out of window

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup

Sometimes clicking on different features close to window boundary makes part of popup out of window's boundary.

[image]

```
layerInfoWindow = new InfoWindowLite(null, domConstruct.create("div", null, null, map.root));
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming from your screenshot that you have your map in another container.  If that is the case and you have more room on the right then just add a css style for the window and increase your z-index.  If you do not want it showing up outside your container then you will need to detect if it is close to the edge of the container then move the placement to correct for the width of the popup.  There are a few good examples and here is that is in the bootstrap code.  This should get you started.  If I have some time later I will try to put up a fiddle.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/tooltip.js

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are using InfoWindowLite and not the standard InfoWindow?  I have never had issues with the standard InfoWindow doing this.

Also, what is the content in your InfoWindow? Images, links, plain text?  This may have something to do with the window resizing after it is opened.

Comment: I have links, tables, plain texts in the InfoWindow.